# Trying to pass an Array to a detailViewController using segues?

Tags: json, ios5, dataview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

Ok so I am trying to pass an array of parsed JSON data to a detailViewController but its sending null data (incorrectly). I am not sure what is wrong with my segue method.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSelectedServers"])
    {
        DetailsViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        detailViewController.data = [_data objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: set a breakpoint on the line where "`detailViewController.data`" gets set... is data valid there or is it null?

Comment: The data is Null, I don't think I am passing the correct data, this is the JSON I am parsing so you can understand what is being sent, http://www.old.hungercraft.net/serverlist.php

Comment: what is "`_data`"?  the JSON data?  You should make sure it's valid even before you enter the "`prepareForSegue:`" method.

Comment: In my UITableView, it correctly shows all the data with the list of servers, I am having issues passing the data about each server to my detailViewController that shows the detailed information of each server (each row).

Comment: What does your `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` look like?

Comment: I do not currently have a `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is that my problem? I made some changes to my code and an IP is being sent over. I think my problem is way too complicated to be resolved over this website. Is there any way I can get in contact with anyone via MSN, IRC, or Skype?